# Ui-Router not working with components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm trying to use the Ui-Router (1.0.0-beta.2) with angular 1.5.x components.

Using this doc : https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component, I came up with something like that :

```
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

export default function config($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            component: 'hello'
        });
}
```

Hello component is like that :

```
class Hello {
    static component() {
        return {
            template: 'Hello component !!!'
        };
    }
}

export default Hello.component();
```

Within my module, I do import/create the component :

```
import AppConfig from './app.config';
import AppComponent from './app.component';
import HelloComponent from './hello.component';

let appModule = angular.module('demo.app', []);

appModule.config(AppConfig);
appModule.component('app', AppComponent);
appModule.component('hello', HelloComponent);
```

**Now, with Ui-Router, If I change the line `component: 'hello'` to `template: '<hello></hello>'` it works.**

What am I missing here ?

I do not want to use template to create the component because I'll need to resolve data thanks to Ui-Router `resolve`.

Thanks for any help !

**EDIT 1:** The project can be found on Github here : https://github.com/maxime1992/web-template-webpack/tree/component-router

The router is defined [here](https://github.com/maxime1992/web-template-webpack/blob/component-router/lib/components/app.config.js)

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, can you double check your angular + ui-router version? Check jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6086onjo/

Comment: you have to check your ui-router version in package.json

Comment: I did double check the ui-router version. It's "1.0.0-beta.2" and I did reinstall my whole project aswel. As I can't figure it out ,I made a temporary commit so you can clone the project if you have some time to help me and try it by yourself. The project is here : https://github.com/maxime1992/web-template-webpack and the router is (https://github.com/maxime1992/web-template-webpack/blob/component-router/lib/components/app.config.js)[here]

Comment: As I mentioned on gitter, you're loading ui-router 0.2.18 via a transitive dependency from `angular-ui-router-anim-in-out`.  Both versions 0.2.18 and 1.0.0-beta.2 are loaded in your webpack bundle, but 0.2.18 is "winning".

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it works like a charm ! I would never have find out because I wrote an `alert('ok');` within my `node_modules/angular-ui-router/realease/angular-ui-router.js` and this file is the latest version for sure. BUT, another one must have been loaded after because of `angular-ui-router-anim-in-out` as you said ! I spend an entire day on that ... Thanks a lot ! (if you want to make a full answer I'd be glad to accept it)